# How to formulate “to see it” in “making my way to Harlem to see it”?

Tags: grammaire, anglais, formulation-idiomatique

A young black woman living in NYC discovers Harlem and goes there often.

"I felt at home, making my way to Harlem to see it."

"to see it" gives me pause here.

Je m'y sentais chez moi, me rendant à Harlem pour découvrir : cela me paraît curieux.

"pour aller voir / pour visiter" ?

Comment: Thanks to @comethapaxd'ajax ’s link, it’s pretty clear to me that she’s not in Harlem to see/visit/discover Harlem, but to see/watch “Paid in Full,” the movie mentioned in the preceding paragraph which if true, should make it easier to understand (and translate) “to see it.”

Comment: Sometimes simple syntax eludes you. Thank you

Comment: pour "le" voir (or "la", depending on context)

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that this sentence is taken from a [novel](https://books.google.com/books?id=OLLsAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT197&dq=%22I%20felt%20at%20home%2C%20making%20my%20way%20to%20Harlem%20to%20see%20it.%22&pg=PT197#v=onepage&q=%22I%20felt%20at%20home%2C%20making%20my%20way%20to%20Harlem%20to%20see%20it.%22&f=false) (thanks to @comethapaxd'ajax for finding this).

Based on the previous paragraph (which describes the speaker's desire to see a movie called *Paid in Full*) and the last sentence of that paragraph (which leads into the OP's sentence):

> "I don't even think *Paid in Full* was showing anywhere lower than 125th Street."

We could translate the OP's sentence as:

> "Je m'y sentais chez moi, me rendant à Harlem pour **le voir**"

("**le**" being the direct article for "**le film** *Paid in Full*")